# Custom conditions in wp query

Tags: wp-query

This is basic query arguments .

```
$loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'project', 'posts_per_page' => -1));
```

Now I want to pass custom arguments like 
1.If it is front page post_type will be "post" and post per page will be "4"
I know how to do it  `is_front_page() {//do stuff here}` .But I want to inject the condition like this way

```
 $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'is_front_page() {//do stuff here}', 'posts_per_page' => -1));
```

Can I do it?

Comment: Why? You can run the condition before the query and simply insert the output.

Comment: Thank you .I know that but thought a bit strange ..

Answer (score 0):

That can't be done, since its translated to sql query I don't see that code executing any where. You'll have to do what @s_ha_dum said.

Do it the other way, its cleaner and readable.